# Content Type for MHT files

Tags: content-type, mhtml

What is the content type for MHT files?

Comment: This resource is quite helpful.
[Webmaster-Toolkit: Mime Types](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

application/octet-stream

You can stream the contents of a .eml file to a browser with this content type and .mht as the extension, and the email will be rendered similar to the way it is rendered in an email client.

Comment: This answer is actually useful in some cases, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15976836/357313

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft, who co-authored the spec for MHT, seem to think that it should be '`message/rfc822`' on [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937912).

No specific MIME type seems to be given in the spec though:
[RFC2557: MIME Encapsulation of Aggregate Documents, such as HTML (MHTML)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557)

Comment: See also here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_3_Message.html: *A Content-Type of "message/rfc822" indicates that the body contains an encapsulated message, with the syntax of an RFC 822 message.*

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but I thought it should be clarified and explained in more detail...

@Guy Starbuck wrote:

> message/rfc822
>
> RFC 822 - STANDARD FOR THE FORMAT OF ARPA INTERNET TEXT MESSAGES

The problem with this answer is that MHTML files ***are not defined by RFC822***.

The correct content-type for MHTML files (.mht, .mhtml) is ***multipart/related***.

As stated above, [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) defines the format for internet *text messages*.  The content-type ***message/rfc822*** is used for text attachments within email messages [1][2].

Most of us have probably received a reply to an email where, instead of being quoted inline, the original message is included as an attachment.  That *attachment* has a content-type of ***message/rfc822***.  In such emails, the content-types break down as follows:

- ***multipart/mixed*** = entire message
- ***text/plain*** = text of reply email
- ***message/rfc822*** = original email as attachment

On the other hand, as noted by @feeela, **MHTML** files are defined in [RFC2557](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2557.txt).  MHTML files are comprised of many different parts, each of which can have a different content-type.  However, RFC2557 defines the content-type of the **entire** file as ***multipart/related***.

[1]  [RFC1341:  MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.txt)
[2]  [The **message** Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_3_Message.html)

Comment: At least in my testing, if you use "multipart/related", IE prompts you to download the file.  If you use "message/rfc822", IE opens it inline.

Comment: `MHT` files are structured in exactly the same way `RFC822`(and following) define the `MAIL` message.

According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046 the `message/rfc822` defines a _composite_ object, which represents a `MAIL` message, where body may be of any type, and header specify, how it should be interpreted.

This said, `message/rfc822` is a closest correct answer, even if it is not explicitly specified.

Another type I've seen used for MHTML files is application/mime, but it will cause filesto be downloaded in most cases.

Comment: `multipart/mixed` is a content-type for message BODY only.

Answer (score 4):

message/rfc822

RFC 822 - STANDARD FOR THE FORMAT OF ARPA INTERNET TEXT MESSAGES

Here is a hyperlink: [message/rfc822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html)

Answer (score 2):

"MIME Encapsulation of Aggregate Documents, such as HTML" (MHTML or MHT) is an IETF standard proposed in 1999 in the [RFC 2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557).

Its MIME type is `multipart/related` and the extension is `.mht`.

See also:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: "multipart/related" would be a MIME type for MHT content. But not for MHT itself.

Comment: @AnrDaemon MIME types always designate contents. It not primarily about the file ending. And: “The content of an MHTML file is encoded as if it were an HTML e-mail message, using the MIME type multipart/related.” Thus this should be correct.

Comment: You're missing the point. MHT has its own MIME header which is a part of the "document body" when you transfer it.