# Modifying the content type of an attachment in a CDO.Message object

Tags: email, vbscript, content-type, email-attachments, mhtml

When I try to add an MHTML file as an attachment to an email message in VBScript, the `ContentMediaType` is incorrectly set to `"message/rfc822"` ([RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822)). From what I understand, this is correct according to Microsoft, but is incorrect according to [RFC 2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557) which states that it should be `"multipart/related"`. This is a problem, because most (if not all) mail clients interpret `"message/rfc822"` as an email message. Since the file extensions `".mht"` and `".mhtml"` do not match any valid file extension of an email message, the mail client appends one of `".msg"`, `".eml"`, etc. to the filename. When a user opens the attachment, it opens as an email message and doesn't display correctly since an MHTML file and an email message are saved differently.

```
Sub SendEmail(FromAddress, ToAddress, Subject, Body, Attachment)
  Call Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next

  Schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
  Set Configuration = Sys.OleObject("CDO.Configuration")
  Configuration.Fields.Item(Schema + "sendusing") = 2
  Configuration.Fields.Item(Schema + "smtpserver") = SMTPServer
  Configuration.Fields.Item(Schema + "smtpserverport") = 25
  Configuration.Fields.Item(Schema + "smtpauthenticate") = 1
  ' Configuration.Fields.Item(schema + "sendusername") = ""
  ' Configuration.Fields.Item(schema + "sendpassword") = ""
  Call Configuration.Fields.Update

  Set Message = Sys.OleObject("CDO.Message")
  Set Message.Configuration = Configuration
  Message.From = FromAddress
  Message.To = ToAddress
  Message.Subject = Subject
  Message.HTMLBody = Body
  If Not IsEmpty(Attachment) Then
    'CDO.Message.AddAttachment doesn't set the correct content media type for an MHTML file.
    Call Message.AddAttachment(Attachment)
  End If

  Call Message.Send
End Sub
```

When I run this code, `Message.Attachments.Item(1).ContentMediaType` is set to `"message/rfc822"`. I need it to be `"multipart/related"` if `Attachment` (a string) ends with `".mht"` or `".mhtml"` (case-insensitive). I can do this with the following code.

```
If Len(Attachment) >= 4 And InStr(Len(Attachment) - 3, Attachment, ".mht", vbTextCompare) Or Len(Attachment) >= 4 And InStr(Len(Attachment) - 5, Attachment, ".mhtml", vbTextCompare) Then
  Message.Attachments.Item(1).ContentMediaType = "multipart/related"
End If
```

For some unknown reason, this undefines the attachment from `Message.Attachments`.

I've looked at manually adding the attachment per [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa488360(v=exchg.65).aspx), but when I call `Message.Attachments.Item(1).Fields.Update`, the object becomes undefined. I think setting the attachments's `ContentMediaType`, implicitly invokes it's `Fields`'s `Update` method which is what I think is responsible for this unexpected behavior.

How can I get around this and send an MHTML file with the `"multipart/related"` content type while maintaining the proper file extension?

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov, I've tried Microsoft Outlook 2010, Apple Mail (on the iPhone), and my web client (Exchange).

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250/content-type-for-mht-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your problem is that at least some email clients save MHTML attachment incorrectly if content type for the attachment is set as `content-type="message/rfc822"`.

First, it is worth noting that your analysis of a root cause of the issue is flawed. You appear to be confused by where `multipart/related` MIME type comes into play. As a matter of fact, [RFC 2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557) does NOT state that *body part corresponding to MHTML attachment* must have `content-type="multipart/related"`. Instead, MIME multipart/related is internal structure of MHTML file itself. Quoting Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML):

> The content of an MHTML file is encoded as if it were an HTML e-mail message, using the MIME type multipart/related.

I.e. if you open MHTML file with text editor, you should see the following:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; ...
```

Microsoft states that MHTML files should be served with `content-type="message/rfc822"` in [KB937912](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937912). This is exactly what CDO does by default when you attach such file via `AddAttachment` method. I believe such behavior does not contradict RFC 2557 in any way. As per the RFC:

> There are a number of document formats... that specify
> documents consisting of a root resource and a number of distinct
> subsidiary resources referenced by URIs within that root resource.
> There is an obvious need to be able to send such multi-resource
> documents in e-mail [SMTP], [RFC822] messages.

> The standard defined in this document specifies how to aggregate such
> multi-resource documents in MIME-formatted [MIME1 to MIME5] messages
> for precisely this purpose.

To recap, you definitely should not set content type of MHTML attachment to `multipart/related`.

While `message/rfc822` seems to be *the* way to use with MHTML files, it obviously triggers the problem you described in the question. I tested with Outlook 2010 and OWA 2010, and was able to reproduce it.

Alternative content types that are used by various email clients for MHTML attachments are `application/octet-stream` and `application/x-mimearchive`. These two didn't exhibit the problem in my tests.

Comment: I appreciate the research on your part. Your last paragraph outlines possible alternative content types, but you do not explain how I can do this. Neither of the approaches that I took would work. I don't updating the content type of an attachment is possible in CDO. Perhaps there is another way to send emails in VBScript?

Comment: @TylerCrompton Updating of attachment's content type certainly *is* possible with CDO. It didn't work for you because you tried to set it to `multipart/related`. Just use `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-mimearchive` in the code you show in the question.